# swift 5: how to check array generic type?

Tags: arrays, generics, types, mirror

```
var array: Array<Int>? = nil
var arrayType: Any.Type = type(of: array)
print("type:\(arrayType)")
```

I got printed:

```
type:Optional<Array<Int>>
```

then, how can i get the type `Int` from `arrayType`?

You may not understand why I did this. The actual situation is:
I have a bean, like this:

```
protocol Initializable {
    init()
}

class MyBean1: Initializable {
    required init() {}
    var property1: Int?
    var property2: String?
}

class MyBean2: Initializable {
    required init() {}
    var beans: Array<MyBean1>?
}
```

I have json data like this:

```
{beans:[{"property1":1,"property2":"string1"},{"property1":2,"property2":"string2"}]}
```

I want automatic create object and set the values.
I use the [Runtime(A Swift Runtime library for viewing type info, and the dynamic getting and setting of properties.)](https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime) Framework to mirror and set properties.
I extend the `TypeInfo`:

```
extension TypeInfo {
    func properties() -> [String] {
        var properties: [String] = []
        for property in self.properties {
            properties.append(property.name)
        }
        return properties
    }
}
```

I want create object from json string:

```
static func fromJson<Result: Initializable>(json: String, type: Result.Type) -> Result {
    var result: Initializable = Result.init()
    if let dictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>.from(json: json) {
        if let info: TypeInfo = try? typeInfo(of: type(of: result)) {
            let properties = info.properties()
            for (key, value) in dictionary {
                if properties.contains(key) {
                    if let property: PropertyInfo = try? info.property(named: key) {
                        print("\(key):\(property.type)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result as! Result
}
```

I got print:

```
beans:Optional<Array<MyBean1>>
```

the `property.type` type is `Any.Type`.
I want get the type `MyBean1` and create MyBean1's object from `property.type`.

Answer (score 0):

Now i use `Bundle.main.classNamed` to get the generic type.
TypeName got from `substring`

```
var typeName = "\(property.type)" // Optional<Array<MyBean1>>
if let range = typeName.range(of: "Optional<") {
    typeName = typeName.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "")
    typeName = String(typeName[typeName.startIndex..<(typeName.index(before: typeName.endIndex))])
}
print("typeName:\(typeName)") // Array<MyBean1>
if let range = typeName.range(of: "Array<") {
    typeName = typeName.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "")
    typeName = String(typeName[typeName.startIndex..<(typeName.index(before: typeName.endIndex))])
    print("typeName:\(typeName)") // MyBean1
    if let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String {
        let clazz: AnyClass? = Bundle.main.classNamed("\(namespace).\(typeName)")
        if let initableType = clazz as? Initializable.Type {
            var beans = Array<Any>()
            for item in array {
                var bean = initableType.init()
                // set bean properties
                beans.append(bean)
            }
        }
    }
}
```